# How do I turn off the backlight (laptop)

Tags: display

I just want to listen to the music, but I have to wait for more than 5 minutes until the led turns off, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just open up the terminal and type this:

```
xset dpms force off
```

Once you press Enter to execute the command, it'll turn off your monitor instantly. This works with every X server. If you press a key or move a mouse, it goes back on (maybe you want to change a song or something). I'm using this method to listen to the music all of the time.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work with an external monitor attached? It turns off both and then they turn right back on.

Comment: It would be good if elementary OS offered an easier way to do this. The UX people may have a view about this, but I think it should be related to the lock screen initiation. For example, if Super+L locks the screen, holding Super and pressing L _twice_ would turn off the back light.

Comment: @andrew79 that discussion should be taken to launchpad or another location.

Comment: @RolandiXor agreed. I have submitted a report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1481461

Comment: I believe that this should be reported as a blueprint, not a bug. Regardless of that, adding a keyboard shortcut to execute the command is trivial. @RolandiXor I don't have an external monitor available at the moment, so it's impossible for me to test out different methods I know of.